# A post about differential equations of order n

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we are given a differential equation like this:
$$F\left ( y, y^{'} ,..., y^{(n)}\right )=0$$
Clearly, this equation doesn't contain the the independent variable $x$ explicitly. The order of this equation is reducible by introducing the substitution : $z=y^{'}$, where $z$ is a function of $y$, hence $z=z(y)$.

**Example**:
$$2y^{'2}=y^{''}(y-1)$$
In this case we set $z$ to be equal to $y^{'}$, and taking all of the above mentioned in consideration we should be able to show that $y^{''}=z\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} y}$. However, I am uncertain I grasped how to get to this equality correctly. The newly introduced function, $z$ should be a composite function of $x$, meaning $z=f(y)=G(x)$. Then I simply rewrote $y^{''}=z\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} y}$ as $y^{''}=\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} y}=\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}$. Am I correct on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y''=\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{dz}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=z\dfrac{dz}{dy}$, we have $2z^2=z\dfrac{dz}{dy}(y-1)$, and to solve this equation should be easy.

The equality $y''=z\dfrac{dz}{dy}$ follows from the chain rule, as shown above.